# how to embed ejb3 in java application?

Tags: java, ejb, ejb-3.2

I am having an java desktop Application, based on the necessary configuration I want to start the ejb container. Is there a embed EJB container I can use?  How can I use only the jboss ejb3 container?  As I don't require web container.

Comment: Have you looked at OpenEJB? I believe it can be embedded and used outside of a web container. http://tomee.apache.org/

Comment: I dont require web container.

Comment: Let me check ... Does it support ejb3.2?

Answer (score 0):

> is there an embed EJB container I can use?

The [Java EE specification](https://www.jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr342/index.html) defines what is called [Application Client Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548130/java-ee-application-client-container), wich seems to be suitable for your requirement.

There are several implementations, for example the one provided by [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beaku.html) or [JBoss](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToUseAnApplicationClientInJBoss-5).